# If a CDS is x%, why does this mean $(1 - x)\%$ probability of default?

Tags: financial-markets

At [11:52](https://youtu.be/mZC6WCE5Bj4?t=712), Tim Bennett says:

> Well let's have a look at
>   11:52
>   some prices. Currently the cost of
>   11:57
>   insuring Greek debt is in excess of
>   12:02
>   $\color{green}{2,000}$ basis points. Another way of
>   12:07
>   looking at that is that you are paying as a
>   12:09
>   premium annually $1/5$th of the value
>   12:12
>   of the debt in question. So another way
>   12:16
>   of looking at that is: the market is
>   12:19
>   effectively giving the chance of Greeks
>   12:20
>   going bust within five years over $\color{red}{80\%}$
>   probability.

Doesn't the cost a Credit Default Swap (CDS) for Greek debt is $\color{green}{20\% (= 2000}$ bp), entail that the chance of default by Greece is also 20%? Why  $\color{red}{80\%}$?

Comment: Your "$1-x$" interpretation may not be what this person had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the 20% annual premium would imply a 20% annual default probability. Tim Bennett is then talking about the probability of default within five years.

He might have thought that
$$
1 - Prob(\text{no default for five years running}) = 1 - (1 - 0.2)^5 > 0.8 
$$
but this is not true as 
$$
1 - (1 - 0.2)^5 \approx 0.67
$$

Answer (score 1):

If x is a [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with probability $p$ then we can use the binomial distribution to calculate, as @Giskard does, the probability that something doesn't happen in n trials (here five) as $1-(1-p)^5$. And, as he or she points out, this implies a probability of about 67% if p=.2.

However, this neglects recovery rates. Think of the price of a CDS per year as (roughly) equally the expected losses per year. In a competitive, relatively efficient market, and with low transaction costs, you pay for insurance what you expect to lose over the same time period. What are the expected losses?

$$E[L] = p_{default} \cdot E[Loss|default]$$

You can see that if the  $E[Loss|default] = LGD = 1$, then the price of the CDS is the expected loss and also the probability of default. If so, then the remainder of the argument is as @Giskard makes it.  However, if the $LGD<1$ is lower then this implies the the probability of default is higher at a given expected loss. For example, at a 55% recovery rate ([at a standard assumed LGD for sovereigns of 45%](http://zinc.zew.de/pub/zew-docs/dp/dp17069.pdf)) and expected loss of 20% per year, the probability of default per year is 44.4%. An annual probability of default of 44.4% implies a 5 year default rate of 94.7%.